# Passing an object to Rest from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rest

Here is the scenario
I have a REST service defined as follow:

```
@Path("/company/{companyName}/sessions")
public class RESTSessionController {

    RESTService service = new RESTService();
     @GET
     @Produces({"application/json"})
     @Path("/{username}/{password}") 
     public Result getFriend(@PathParam ("companyName") String companyName ,
             @PathParam ("username") String username,
             @PathParam ("password") String password){

         System.out.println(companyName);
         return service.login(username,password);
     }
}
```

To call this I have a javascript as follow:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/rest/company/hertz/sessions/amir/help',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: null,
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#abc").html(dumpObj(data,"Result",'',0));
         }
    });
```

This works fine and I get this back:

```
{"code":"200","description":"Amir is now logged in.","payload":{"@type":"xs:string","$":"Amir123"}}
```

which is perfectly fine.

Now I'm trying to go one step further and call my service using an object so I changed my code to:

```
$.ajax({
    qObj={username:"Amir",password:"123",companyName:"hertz"}
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/rest/company/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(qObj),
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#abc").html(dumpObj(data,"Result",'',0));
         }
    });
```

And it won't work.

My question is simple, how to I call a REST service with parameter in the path (or without it) using jquery/javascript?

Thx for the help

Amir

Comment: I know this is off topic, but using a `GET` request to log a user in sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: I think he is just playing around with jquery otherwise this is a very bad practice since password is not hashed on top of what you mentioned.

Comment: Jay, thx for the comment, Quynh is right, this is simply me trying to build my framework and make sure I have all I need before starting the main application. Your both comments are valid about using GET and plain password.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution
In case you are looking for the same answer here are my findings:
1) You can't user variables used in the path as part of your objects sent to REST services. So in my case {companyName} couldn't be really be passed as part of json object.
2) In method declaration it has to be a directive to indicate this method expects a json object, this was the case so I changed my code to:

```
 @PUT
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Path("/")
 public API_Session login(API_Session_Request request){
```

and all worked like a charm.

3) In javascript you should use the JSON.stringify your object:

```
var qObj={username:"Amir",password:"123",company_name:"hertz"}
$.ajax({
    type:'PUT',
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/rest/company/sessions',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(qObj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#abc").html(dumpObj(data,"Result",'',0));
         }
    });
```

Hope this helps you to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have to use JSON.stringify? Try this and let me know :)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/rest/company/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {username:"Amir",password:"123",companyName:"hertz"},
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#abc").html(dumpObj(data,"Result",'',0));
         }
    });
```

Comment: Tried this and the same result. It's getting 404 page not found result form Jersey.

Comment: I see 4 parameters here /hertz/sessions/amir/help but your data only contains 3.

Comment: Sessions is part of the path, it's not the parameter.

Comment: ok, try this @Path("/company/sessions/{companyName}") and change your url path inside the ajax call. So. all of your url should be 'http://localhost:8888/rest/company/sessions/'